# 404 when file is on server

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

Trying to access [a simple PHP script](http://dardesarchat.ir/findme.php) with a browser I can find it. However, trying to access it through `curl` or `get_headers` I get a 404 result. For instance

```
$url = 'http://dardesarchat.ir/findme.php';
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    [Date] => Sat, 28 Jun 2014 19:38:34 GMT
    [Server] => Apache/2
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Vary] => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => text/html
)
```

This is not dns related, because trying `get_headers` with `http://dardesarchat.ir/index.html` returns `[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, it's only the PHP file that *cannot be found*!

This is not also PHP related (returning 404 on purpose if some cookie is missing, etc.). The code in findme.php is this:

```
<?php
die('I sure am here :P');
?>
```

Finally, there is no `htaccess` file on the host. How could this be?

Comment: I tried to curl from here and it works. Are you perhaps trying to `curl` / `get_headers` from the hosting server itself? Sometimes Apache is not configured to listen to localhost...

Comment: @Khôi, this is happening to a remote installer, where I have the master script on the main server, and slave on this server. The remote installer has successfully installed 30+ instances of the app with this exact arrangement, all of a sudden though it is giving this strange result for this particular domain.

Comment: Hard to tell still, is the `index.html` really the one you're expecting? Does `dardesarchat.ir` resolve to the right server / IP on the slave machine? I guess it could be any index.html you're getting there.

Comment: @Khôi, good point! I will add a `findme.html` to check if that is the case or is it somehow related to file type.

Comment: @Khôi, you are right! `http://dardesarchat.ir/findme.html` returns 404 too! So, it should be DNS related, and could we say DNS records have been updated in some sub-nets and not on others?

Comment: There's a good probability that it is a DNS issue. But it can be a  `/etc/hosts` issue as well. Or a misconfigured DNS Server in `resolv.conf`. But yes, you're at least in the right direction now.

Comment: @Khôi, thanks for the great help. If you care to add your advise as an answer, I'd happily mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting general network problems:

Most common issues are always DNS issues.

1. Check if your client computer can resolve the server properly (`nslookup` and `ping` from the client computer should display the correct IP). Look out for IPv4 and IPv6 too, since Apache servers often only listen on IPv4 connections.
2. Check if you have strange configuration in `/etc/hosts` (or `\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on windows).
3. `curl / wget index.html` might get you any `index.html` if that server happens to have a Webserver installed.
4. Check what DNS Servers are configured in your client computer (`/etc/resolv.conf`)

Other possible error sources:

- Is the client computer behind a (transparent) proxy?
- Is the client computer in a strange network with even stranger routing tables on the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using the exact same code as you did I get a HTTP 200 response.

```
$url = 'http://dardesarchat.ir/findme.php';
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
```

Gives me:

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I don't see any problems here.

Comment: I still get 404, and cannot think of *any* reason this could happen.